# Heat equation with no boundary conditions

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, heat-equation

The task: 
solve this problem on $R\times R_{+}: $
$U_{t}=U_{xx}+cos x$,
$U(0, x)=exp(2x)$

We've only solved problems like this with Poisson's formula, which requires the function $U(0,x)$ to be bounded. How this is not the case in this problem, I don't know how to proceed. The only other method we did for such equations is separating variables, but I need boundary conditions for that.

Answer (score 1):

The function $v(t,x)=\exp(2x+4t)$ is clearly a solution of the homogeneous problem, so put $U=v+w$.  Then $w$ solves the Cauchy problem
\begin{align}
w_t&=w_{xx}+\cos x,\\
w|_{t=0}&=0.
\end{align}
To solve this, use the method of undetermined coefficients.  Seek a solution of the form
$$
w(t,x)=A(t)\cos x,
$$
where, to satisfy the initial condition, we want $A(0)=0$.  Substituting this ansatz into the PDE for $w$ and equating the coefficient of $\cos x$ equal to zero, we obtain the Cauchy problem
\begin{align}
A'(t)&=-A(t)+1,\\
A|_{t=0}&=0.
\end{align}
Hence, $A(t)=1-e^{-t}$, and $w(t,x)=(1-e^{-t})\cos x$.  This yields $U$.

Comment: Note: it's natural to ask how I found $v(t,x)$.  This choice of $v$ arises from separation of variables.  Indeed, the general (nontrivial) separated solution $v(t,x)=A(t)B(x)$ to $v_t=v_{xx}$ is $v(t,x)=a\exp(\lambda^2 t+\lambda x)$, where $a,\lambda\in\mathbb C$.  But this initial condition $\exp(2x)$ is precisely of this form if $\lambda=2$.